# Display full screen images on multi-display system without event loop in Python

Tags: python, image, raspberry-pi, fullscreen

I would like to display full-screen images on multi-display system without event loop in Python. I looked at a few GUI libraries, but they have mandatory event loop, which makes the task a bit convoluted. I need a library call, which displays a full-screen image, returns immediately and doesn't trigger OS (Raspberry Pi OS) warning about an inactive GUI task. Is there a mainstream library, which can do it in a simple way?

Comment: I don't think any library can really do that (at least not in a simple way), that would have to be a very specific feature, why can't you have the event loop?

Comment: @Matiiss It will run on a headless system, so there will be no events to process. Just looking to simplify the design.